# Chromecast CAF takes longer time to download video segments

Tags: chromecast

For the same video segment chromecast CAF receiver takes longer time to download comparing with PWA, android etc.

By say `same video segment`, I mean same host(url).

Things I have tried:

1. In CAF receiver inspector, I tracked the time taken for each segment to download. Then I played with web browser on the same segments. The time taken for chromecast to download each segment is tripled.
2. Copy the segment host url, use my macbook terminal: `wget + segment host` It only takes 0.5 seconds to download the segment, where in chromecast it takes 3-10 seconds to download.

Comment: Should [this (Known Issue: Slow Wi-Fi performance with Android and Chromecast built-in devices)](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/7634752?hl=en&ref_topic=3447927) be related to what you are experiencing?

Comment: Hi @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0, thanks for replying. It is not the same issue.